# jquery select multiple and display to specific container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day!
I have a problem with jQuery multi-select.
**For example:** 
I have **5 links** and **3 containers**. Every time a specific link is pressed it will display to the container and I want to select **3 links** to put to the **3 containers**. Since I have 5 links, when I want to click the remaining links the container will then change the value according to the link pressed.

**HTML Code:**

```
<a id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a id="link2">Link 2</a>
<a id="link3">Link 3</a>
<a id="link4">Link 4</a>
<a id="link5">Link 5</a>

<ul id="container">
  <li id="container1>Container 1<li>
  <li id="container2>Container 2<li>
  <li id="container3>Container 1<li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#container1, #container2, #container3').hide();
$('#link1').click(function () {
  $('#container1').show();
});
$('#link2').click(function () {
  $('#container2').show();
});
$('#link3').click(function () {
  $('#container3').show();
});
```

Please help me I am still new in jQuery. I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and your jquery code that you have tried yet so far?

Comment: your question is unclear....

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want the links to move into the containers? What are the criteria? first link to first container? where do the other 2 go? Also, you cannot have `id`s that are the same

Comment: Sorry guys. I just updated my question.

Comment: This part is still unclear "Since I have 5 links, when I want to click the remaining links the container will then change the value according to the link pressed." Which container will change on the 4th and 5th click? The last container?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1vfe3ay5/1/  It is very rough programming though. If you explain what you are trying to do exactly, and why, there must be a better way to achieve the results you are looking for.

Comment: @Cory That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple demo

The demo only do is that, if the user click on the link
then it will be going to the container then the link that was click will be hiding
to the link selection.

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" class="link">Link 5</a>

<ul id="container">
  <li class="linklist" data-contain = "false" id="container1">Stuff in 1</li>
  <li class="linklist" data-contain = "false" id="container2">Stuff in 2</li>
  <li class="linklist" data-contain = "false" id="container3">Stuff in 3</li>
</ul>
```

The javascript ::

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

  // hope you are getting the idea

  // bind event on class link
  $(document).on('click', '.link', function () {

    var link = $(this);
    // get link name
    var link_name = link.text();


    // select container
    var con = $(".linklist[data-contain=false]").first();
      // change the attribute
      con.attr('data-contain', true);
      // change the html contain
      con.html(link_name);
      // show
      con.show();
      // hide the click link
      link.hide();

      // you can do more.. like create a option that
      // you can also delete the selected link on the container
      // list and show the link again to be selected

  });

});


</script>
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ku3683Lr/)

Comment: This is also good but I don't want to hide the link. It will be still remain.

Comment: @johnlopev If you want the link to remain/not to hide then you can comment out the line link.hide()